# Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, jndi, jta

I am trying to configure JTA Transactions with Atomkios in Tomcat 5.5 for jndi support
    I am using spring,jpa+hybernate 
 when i m trying to access my database, i am getting the error like this

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82)
 org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:572)
 org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:636)
 org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:665)
 org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:673)
 org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713)
 com.evolvus.springsecurity.impl.CustomJdbcDaoImpl.loadUsersByUsername(CustomJdbcDaoImpl.java:78)
 org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:152)
 com.evolvus.springsecurity.impl.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider.java:27)
 org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:120)
 org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:48)
 com.evolvus.springsecurity.impl.LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:38)
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
 org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:109)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
 org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

my config.xml

```
<beans: bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" >
  <beans: property name="jndiName">
   <beans:value>java:comp/env/jdbc/welcome</beans:value>
  </beans: property>   
 </beans: bean>
and i configure data source in tomcat5.5/config/context.xml       


   <Resource name="jdbc/welcome"  
     auth="Container" 
     type="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean" 
     factory="com.atomikos.tomcat.BeanFactory"
     uniqueResourceName="jdbc/myDB"
     xaDataSourceClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource"
     maxPoolSize="3"
     minPoolSize="1"
     xaProperties.databaseName="payhub"
     xaProperties.url="jdbc\:mysql\://devserver\:3306/payhub" 
     />
```

and in my application web.xml is

```
<resource-ref>
   <description>PaymentsDatabase</description>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/welcome</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
   <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

what mistake i have done here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must specify your Context like: for example:

**META-INF/context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Resource
    name="jdbc/database"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="4"
    maxIdle="2"
    username="root"
    maxWait="5000"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    password="password"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name"/>
</Context>
```

**WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<web-app>
...
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/app-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
...
    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/database</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

**app-context.xml**

```
...
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourcejndi" jndi-name="jdbc/database"
        lookup-on-startup="false" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"
        cache="true" resource-ref="true" />
...
<beans: bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourcejndi" /> 
 </beans: bean>
...
```

Hope helps...

Comment: why do I need META-INF/context.xml