# Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null' java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring, tomcat

The server loads fine (with no errors or warnings) however, certain images don't display correctly. I had to fiddle around with class paths to get the server running so I'm wondering if its something to do with that? Anyway heres my log, would really appriciate some help. I only recieve errors when I switch between a few pages...

```
    29-Aug-2011 15:46:36 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Symantec\pcAnywhere\;C:\Program Files\Open Text\Livelink Explorer\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Symantec\pcAnywhere\;C:\Program Files\Open Text\Livelink Explorer\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\tools\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;C:\tools\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin
29-Aug-2011 15:46:36 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
29-Aug-2011 15:46:36 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 451 ms
29-Aug-2011 15:46:36 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
29-Aug-2011 15:46:36 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.20
29-Aug-2011 15:46:37 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
Continuing ...
29-Aug-2011 15:46:38 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
29-Aug-2011 15:46:39 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
29-Aug-2011 15:46:39 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
29-Aug-2011 15:46:39 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/47  config=null
29-Aug-2011 15:46:39 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2868 ms
29-Aug-2011 15:47:22 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'main'
Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:507)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:476)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:253)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1143)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:328)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:404)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:412)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.query(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:109)
    at com.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz.dao.AirQualityJdbcDao.getAirQualityDistricts(AirQualityJdbcDao.java:26)
    at com.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz.services.AirQualityServiceImpl.getAirQualityDistricts(AirQualityServiceImpl.java:116)
    at com.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz.services.AirQualityServiceImpl.getCurrentHighMediumAirQualityDistricts(AirQualityServiceImpl.java:37)
    at com.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz.services.NewsServiceImpl.getAirQualityAlertsInNews(NewsServiceImpl.java:166)
    at com.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz.web.controllers.NewsReaderController.handleRequestInternal(NewsReaderController.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:857)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:475)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:430)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.template_tag._jspx_meth_c_005fimport_005f1(template_tag.java:816)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.template_tag.doTag(template_tag.java:297)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.main.map_jsp._jspx_meth_westsussex_005ftemplate_005f0(map_jsp.java:369)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.main.map_jsp._jspService(map_jsp.java:171)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:243)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:475)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:430)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:507)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:476)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:253)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1143)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:328)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:404)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:412)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.query(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:109)
    at com.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz.dao.AirQualityJdbcDao.getAirQualityDistricts(AirQualityJdbcDao.java:26)
    at com.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz.services.AirQualityServiceImpl.getAirQualityDistricts(AirQualityServiceImpl.java:116)
    at com.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz.services.AirQualityServiceImpl.getCurrentHighMediumAirQualityDistricts(AirQualityServiceImpl.java:37)
    at com.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz.services.NewsServiceImpl.getAirQualityAlertsInNews(NewsServiceImpl.java:166)
    at com.xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz.web.controllers.NewsReaderController.handleRequestInternal(NewsReaderController.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:8
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256592/cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-for-connect-url-null)

Comment: "certain images don't display" does it mean that the application can load some images from the database and some not?

Comment: One image displays fine.

Comment: I'm also getting

SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet feed
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet feed threw exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a while ago, but incase this helps anyone - I think my problem was the way I build the project.